# Entity query returns wrong NID

Tags: database, entities

I have the following query:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','article');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Then I want to access all content:

```
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple(array_keys($result));
```

But in variable $results, there are wrong NIDs. My first article ID is '12' and second article '13'. But in $result are '9' and '10'

Do you have an explanation for this?

Ok, I found out I can't use array_keys... because keys are not same as IDs. Proved just now in an easy example... in my $result[9] there is the right id '12'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of [Query::execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Config!Entity!Query!Query.php/function/Query%3A%3Aexecute/8.2.x),

> int|array Returns an integer for count queries or an array of ids. The
>   values of the array are always entity ids. The keys will be revision
>   ids if the entity supports revision and entity ids if not.

Nodes support revisions so the keys will be revision ids and not entity ids.

```
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple(array_values($result));
```

Comment: Do you know why to use `array_values()` in `loadMultiple()` ?

Comment: @JoshuaGraham, `$result` is an associative array of entity ids _keyed by_ revision id. The `::loadMultiple` method takes an array parameter expecting entity ids.

Comment: Would Drupal 'try' to load revision ids of 0,1,2,3, etc for array_values() for an array of 4 items them? (they would be the number keys then, instead of the revision id number keys)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `array_values($result)` represents an indexed array of entity ids where as `array_keys($result)` is an indexed array of Revision ids. `::loadMultiple` would try to load entities with entity ids equal to the revision ids in the latter case, which would not be the expected output base don the question.